# Retrieve prestashop orders 1.6.1

Tags: php, prestashop

Do you know what code I should use to (automaticaly) retrieve the last prestashop orders? My goal is to use these informations to stock them in xml files and send them on a ftp server.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: But are you trying to retrieve them from a PS module or from an external script? And what have you already tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Prestashop webservice

Please see below

for 1.6
http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Web+service+tutorial

for 1.7
http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS17/Webservice